# Global variable problem, when function callback, the variable does not change

Tags: javascript

There is a problem that if I want to pass a global variable with a call back function, then the global variable does not change as a parameter, although it appears in the example code to increase continuously by one, but only 1 is passed continuously as a parameter.

```js
var active = 1;
function scope(condition) {
  active++;
  console.log(condition); //Why always 1?
}
function click(example) {
  window.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (example) {
      example();
    }
    console.log(active);
  });
}
click(scope.bind(this, active));
```

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: When you call `.bind()`, you bind the value of the parameter **at that moment**. It does not cause the parameter expression to be re-evaluated whenever the bound function is called.

Comment: And how could it be solved to pass the new variable as a parameter, but the function calls are unchanged: click(scope(active))? Is there any other solution?

Comment: You could pass nothing and have no parameter.

Comment: You should never use global variable, but write pure functions